# How do I dynamically change the src attribute of a collection of images in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image

I have a document which has a specific path to images set:

`<img src="img/xxx.xxx"> // img in this case`

What I'd like to do is change them all dynamically:

`<img src="/new/path/xxx.xxx">`

This is my code:

```
  var doc = document,
      img = doc.getElementsByTagName('img'),
      emailUrl = '/img/g',
      imgSrc;

 for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    imgSrc = img[i].src;
    imgSrc = imgSrc.replace(emailUrl, '/new/path/');
 }
```

I stepped through the debugger and it doesn't seem to add them? What am I missing?

Comment: You never assign `img[i].src = img[i].src.replace(...)`

Comment: can you add a class for all image tag?

Comment: @Thinker — What would be the point of that? A class is just a way of defining a group of elements. When you want the group of "All img elements" then you can get them by type as the OP is already doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign the replacement to the `img.src`. Regex is also not a string.

Also, it is important to note that when you are using relative paths, the browser may fill in the beginning portion of the URL. In the following example, you can see that the final result contains the full URL that the image was relative too. That will be important for you to remember as you set up your regular expressions.

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
  emailUrl = /\/img\//;

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  console.log('Before', imgs[i].src);
  imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/new/path/');
  console.log('After', imgs[i].src);
}
```

```html
<img src="img/xxx.xxx">
<img src="img/xxx.xxx">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help KevBot, my only question is, could you explain why doesn't `imgSrc = img[i].src` do the same the same as `imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src`?

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz, `imgSrc` was created as a variable. Since it is a variable, it is just stored in memory. There is no further reference to the original `img.src` in this context. That variable has 1 purpose at that moment in time, and it is to store what was the `src` when you assigned it. So, in order to reassign it, you have to do it on the element. `img.src = ...`. Does that make sense?

Comment: So I'd have to do `imgs[i].src = imgSrc.src.replace(emailUrl, '/new/path/'); ` to get it to be reassigned. I guess I am confused because I thought I was storing a reference to an object,  `img` in this case.

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz Yep, you'd have to do that. If you wanted to store a reference to the `img`, in this case you would have to do it inside of the loop:
`myImg = imgs[i]`, however, even then, you would still have to do `myImg.src = "newSrc"`. 
The point is that in order to reassign the `src`, you have to either call it with `.src = ` or something like `.setAttribute('src', "newSrc")`. Both of them are operations that have to be explicitly called in order for the source to be reassigned.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

*First*:

Strings are immutable. `replace` doesn't change the *in place*. You're assigning the result to the `imgSrc` variable and then … not doing anything with it.

*Second*:

`'/img/g'` is not a regular expression, it is [a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals). Don't quote it if you want a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#RegExp_literals).

Answer (score 1):

You set new src to `imgSrc`, but not to `img[i].src`.
Try to do so:

```
img[i].src = img[i].src.replace(/img/g, '/new/path/');
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dweknwz5/) for you!

The trick is this:

```
img[i].src = imgSrc.replace(emailUrl, '/new/path/');
```

but beware the typos: document, not doc.

Comment: Thanks I edited my post, I forgot to add `doc = document` :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assing the `imgSrc` to `img[i].src`. Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    imgSrc = img[i].src.replace(emailUrl, '/new/path/');
    img[i].src = imgSrc;
 }
```